# Scraping network traffic data

Tags: json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, network-traffic

I'm well aware of scraping webpages with requests, BS, and a few other tools, but I can't seem to find a way to create a program that scrapes stuff found in the network tab in Google Chrome Dev tools. There's a website I want to scrape that nicely has what I need in JSON. Is there any way to access this with Python 3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could create a python HTTP proxy server, and set your `http_proxy` environment variable assuming you're using windows, or configure it through Chrome proxy settings.

Comment: What do you mean by scrape stuff in the networks tab? Do you want to record it, make the same post/get as a site or something third?

Comment: @jlaur sorry for the late reply, but yes, I'd like for it to save the information I'm looking for in a text or JSON file.

Comment: Then use requests to do the same GET/POST as you see in the networks tab.